# Envió de información a base de datos MYSQL a través de AJAX

Tags: ajax

el siguiente código pretende enviar información a la base de datos MYSQL a través de ajax. En concreto estoy desarrollando una extensión de chrome para que coja la url donde estoy trabajando, la envíe a la base de datos y me devuelva un mensaje. La base de datos se compone de 2 filas, en una están las urls y la otra el [mensajetienda] que quiero que de en cada una de esas urls.
Esta es la codificación, pero no consigo ejecutarla:

```
              <meta charset="utf-8"/>
              <?php

              $webactual= window.location.href
              $resultadoConsulta= '';
              $msg = 'Hola gracias por comprar en nuestra tienda'.$resultadoConsulta;
              $link = mysqli_connect("aquiNombreServidor", "aquiUsuario", "aquiPassword");
              mysqli_select_db($link, "prueba1");

              while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($webactual)){
              $resultadoConsulta .= ','.$fila['mensajetienda'];
              }

              echo $msg.$resultadoConsulta;

              mysqli_close($link);

              ?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué depuraciones has hecho y qué errores/resultados/mensajes tienes?

Comment: php es un lenguaje de servidor, estás intentando ejecutarlo en un script en un navegador? Un navegador no sabe interpretar php, por otro lado, `window.location.href` es javascript... estás mezclando php y javascript. Has puesto etiqueta de ajax, pero tu código es php! Te recomiendo que mires algún tutorial de ajax para entender lo básico, ya que ajax se ejecuta en JavaScript, y hace ***llamadas*** a php, eso no significa que se escriba en php

Comment: Además te recomiendo mirar algún tutorial de php y mysql... `mysqli_fetch_array($webactual)` es literalmente -> `mysqli_fetch_array(www.webenlaqueestas.com)`, eso no tiene sentido puesto que el `mysqli_fetch_array` requiere una query